# How to wrap text that is displayed in a <div> with bootstrap form-control and dropdown classes?

Tags: css, razor, bootstrap-4, blazor-client-side

I have a razor page where I am displaying the list of selected items from a dropdown menu in a div tag. How can I get @FormattedText auto wrap if the list of items selected exceeds the size of the div.

I tried to apply word-wrap and white-space styles and neither of them worked. The content extends beyond the  and the scroll bars are displayed. How can I wrap the content within the ? Thanks for any suggestions!

```
<style>
    .dropdown {
       word-wrap: normal;
       white-space: normal;
    }
</style>


<div class="form-control col-md-4 dropdown dropdown-toggle">
        @FormattedText

        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" @bind="item.IsUpdated" />
                    <label for="@item.Name">@item.Name</label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
</div>

List<string> selectedItems = new List<string>();

public string FormattedText
{
    get
    {
        selectedItems.Clear();

        selectedItems.AddRange(Items.Where(s => s.IsUpdated).Select( item => { return item.Name; }));
        
        if (selectedItems.Any())
        {
            return string.Join(",", selectedItems.ToArray());
        }
     }

    set
    {
        selectedText = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your Bootstrap `.dropdown` structure is not correct. If you look at [their examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/#single-button), `.dropdown-toggler` and `.dropdown-menu` need to be the same level, wrapped by `.dropdown`. Also each item in `.dropdown-menu` needs to have `.dropdown-item` class as well.

So you need to change the structure to:

```
<div class="form-control col-md-4">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggler"
          data-toggle="dropdown">
            @FormattedText
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                <div class="dropdown-item">
                    <input type="checkbox" @bind="item.IsUpdated" />
                    <label for="@item.Name">@item.Name</label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
</div>
```

It will look something like this:

[image]

The reason why the formatted text, wrapped in the button, is not wrapping is because `.dropdown-toggler` has style `white-space: nowrap;`. You can get rid of that style or use Bootstrap utility class `.text-wrap` on the `.dropdown-toggler`

```
<div class="form-control col-md-4">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggler text-wrap"
          data-toggle="dropdown">
            @FormattedText
        </button>

    ...

</div>
```

Lastly the dropdown is out of the `.form-control`'s border. That's because `.form-control` has a fixed height. You can set its height style to auto, or use Bootstrap utility class `.h-auto`:

```
<div class="form-control col-md-4 h-auto">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggler text-wrap"
          data-toggle="dropdown">
            @FormattedText
        </button>

    ...

</div>
```

Now the whole thing looks like this:

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/3bykc4rf/14/